# Flash Builder 4.7 fails on debugging on android device

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, air-native-extension

I'm creating an app including native extensions (.ane)

At the moment it's already working on iOS, but I want to add an extension for android as well.

Now, i've done all necessary steps to do so and want to debug on a device. But whenever I try to start the Debugger, I get the following error, and I don't know how to fix this.

I am able to create a 'release build', though. Unfortunately, after startup, the app hangs.

I do not know, however, if it's a building or a coding issue causing the crash, therefore I need the Debugger.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyAppWithExtension".

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.utils.ANE.AppXMLFileANEExtensionHandler.retainExtensionIds(AppXMLFileANEExtensionHandler.java:309)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.utils.ANE.ANEController.modifyAppXMLforPackaging(ANEController.java:360)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.utils.ANE.ANEController.modifyAppXMLforPackaging(ANEController.java:326)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.utils.ANE.AbstractANEPackageHandler.modifyAppXMLforPackaging(AbstractANEPackageHandler.java:86)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform.launchhandlers.AbstractMultiPlatformLaunchHandler.handleANEPackagingDetails(AbstractMultiPlatformLaunchHandler.java:195)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform.launchhandlers.AbstractMultiPlatformLaunchHandler.applyPackagingDetails(AbstractMultiPlatformLaunchHandler.java:168)
at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android.launching.ADBLaunchHandler.initialisePackager(ADBLaunchHandler.java:533)
at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android.launching.ADBLaunchHandler.doPackage(ADBLaunchHandler.java:409)
at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android.launching.ADBLaunchHandler.launch(ADBLaunchHandler.java:350)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform.MultiPlatformLaunchDelegate.launch(MultiPlatformLaunchDelegate.java:184)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.launch(AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.java:244)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.launch(AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.java:134)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Session Data:

eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_51
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/myusername/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/myusername/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

This is a continuation of log file /Users/myusername/PathToMy/Workspaces/MyAppWithExtension/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2013-07-24 11:43:14.053
```

Many Thanks in advance, Timm

EDIT: This is what I've done so far, but no luck :(

- Created new workspace
- Run Flash Builder with -clean parameter at startup
- Reinistalled Flash Builder using Adobe Clean Tool
- cleaned all bin-debug bin-release-temp and other project related temp folders I'm aware of.

Comment: Are you including an ANE that is not set to work with Android? ANEs are platform specific (for obvious reasons). You can make them work on all platforms, but most ANEs that you find online do not do this (only the well-developed ones do). Does it display an error when you try to debug?

Comment: @JoshJanusch Hi there, thanks for asking. I developped the ane myself, and in fact it was already working (and also debugging) in FB 4.6. I set up the extension xml to support android. Recently, I updated both, the (java) code of the android part of the extension and Flash Builder. Now I keep running into problems, mostly when compiling or debugging. The concrete error I get from the FB GUI is: "Java null pointer exception" (I get these quite often these days, in lots of contexts ;) I will also edit my question to reflect, what I've done so far to solve the issue. thx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of experimenting, I finally found the reason for the problem.
It seems Flash Builder had problems with the structure of my project, namely I had 2 executable applications in it.

Removing one, either by deleting or by deactivating over the Project->Settings->Applications dialog, finally fixed it.

I hope this helps anybody facing the same annoying Flash Builder issue.

Answer (score 0):

- How does you appName-app.xml looks like? Look at the end of the file, does the `<extensionID>` match the ANE/extension.xml `<extension>`/`<id>`?
- Did you build your ANE with the same sdk than your main project?
- Are the files referenced by `<nativeLibrary>` really included in the ANE (open it with an archiver)?
- Did you well implement functions referenced in extension.xml's `<initializer>` & `<finalizer>`?

Comment: That's a bunch of questions, you have, not an answer ;) But many thanks anyway! I can answer anything with 'yes', except for the sdk I built my ane with, but I'm not sure, if that is important. The .ane is built with air 3.1 (need this for PlayBook compatibility), and the release-builds for iOS and BlackBerry are working fine. I just can't debug, which is a problem, because the Android part is not working.

Comment: Sorry to us notification this way, but I'm just not sur if it works, since everything after the (at) is sometimes omitted from the comment on my system @JérômeGillard

Answer (score 0):

In case you have this exception when using an ANE AND a Coldfusion Server, change the Output folder in the Project Properties > Flex Server > Output folder to something like "temp" instead of "C:..." generated by Flex Builder. The Android device gets confused by a "C:" reference but still can understand a "temp" local folder

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Not sure how i can explain it better :) So if you are getting this exception while using some ANE and is using a ColdFusion server in the same go, the problem is that the default output folder that Flash Builder is creating under Project Properties > Flex Server > Output folder starts with "C:\...". When you try to debug it on the device, the device tries to resolve the "C:\..." Path and fails generating an exception.   So the solution is to change the output folder path to something like just "temp". This folder will work for both computer and device